# Couldn't install Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

Im having these problem after installing ASP.net on Visual Studio 2017

//Couldn't install Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature

> Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature,version=15.7.27520.0'
>   failed to install.
>       Search URL
>           https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=87
>       Details
>           Command executed: "C:\Windows\system32\dism.exe" /online /quiet /norestart /Enable-Feature
>   /FeatureName:"netfx4extended-aspnet45" /All
>   /logPath:"C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20180624000214_074_Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature.log"
>           Return code: 87
>           Return code details: No file path specified.
>       Log
>           C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20180624000214_074_Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature.log
>       Impacted workloads
>           ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.7.27625.0)
>       Impacted components
>           Advanced ASP.NET features (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AspNet45,version=15.7.27625.0)

Answer (score -1):

As per thread https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/175324/couldnt-install-microsoftvisualstudioaspnet45featu.html this issue has been fixed in latest Visual Studio update. Please install latest Visual Studio update and then try.